# SQL Server - date comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN '04/10/2006' < '07/01/2013' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'
END
```

Output: TRUE

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN '10/31/2006' > '07/01/2012' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' 
END
```

Output: TRUE

This is so confusing. I executed these two query and I got o/p as true for both the queries. The o/p to 1st query is correct. Shouldn't the output to 2nd query be false.? Can someone help please?

Comment: Your comparing strings but not dates. Either use DATE or specify the strings in `YYYY-MM-DD`format.

Comment: your query doesn't compare DATES, it compares STRINGS

Comment: SQL doesn't know you want your date strings (i.e., `'10/31/2006'`) to be treated as dates, so it is treating them as strings.  Explicitly CAST them to DATETIME datatype first.

Answer (score 3):

Those are strings without an explicit or implicit conversion to a `date` datatype.

The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Try this:

```
select 
   case  
   when convert(date,'20060410') < convert(date,'20130701') then 'true'
   else 'false'
   end

select 
   case  
   when convert(date,'20061031') > convert(date,'20120701') then 'true'
   else 'false'
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use standard date formats.  Then you won't have a problem.  I prefer YYYY-MM-DD, which will be converted to a correct date under almost all circumstances (if you leave out the hyphens, the conversion will always work):

```
 select  (case '2006-04-10' < '2013-07-01' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'
          end) as output_1
         (case  '2006-10-31 > '2012-07-01' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'
          end) as output_2
```

When you use the correct format, the comparisons will work as either strings or dates.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings not dates, so that you firstly have to cast it to dates then you can compare it.

Here is the solution of your problem:

SELECT
   CASE WHEN Cast('10/31/2006' as datetime) > Cast('07/01/2012' as datetime) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' 
END

Enjoy!!